# Matlab function that returns gradient

Tags: matlab, gradient

I'm trying to create a function, that has two output arguments:
 1. The calculated f(x) value
 2. The gradient

But it's calling itself recursively all the time.
What am I doing wrong?

```
function [y, gra] = f1(x)
y = x^2
syms z
gra = gradient(f1(z))
```

Thanks.

edit:
Now I have this:

```
function [y, gra] = f1(x)
y = x^2
if nargout == 2
    syms x
    gra = gradient(f1(x))
end
```

edit 2:

I'm trying to use the function in the following:

```
[y, grad] = f1(5);
y_derived = grad(10);
```

Comment: How are you trying to use this function? Can you show us an example of how you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
function [y, gra] = f1(x)
f=@(x) x^2;

y=f(x); %// calculate y

syms z %// initialise symbolic variable
gra=gradient(f(z),z); %// symbolic differentiation
```

This will return `g` as a symbolic function. To calculate a value, you can use `subs(gra,z,123)`, or, if you are going to evaluate it many times, do `gradFunc=matlabFunction(gra)` then `gradFunc(v)` where `v` is a vector or matrix of points you want to evaluate.

Comment: Yup.  This makes sense.  This is another classic case where the person providing the answer knows more about what the OP is asking and wants than the OP him/herself lol.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the argument into `gradient` is your function name `f1(z)`.  As such, it keeps calling `f1` when your original function is also called `f1`, and so the function keeps calling itself until you hit a recursion limit.

I think you meant to put `gradient(y)` instead.  Try replacing your `gradient` call so that it is doing:

```
gra = gradient(y);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! But my question is, can I create a function that returns the gradient also as a function, and not already evaluated?

Comment: @vardump - Before I do that, I need more details on how `f1` works.  What exactly is `x`?  I don't see any function evaluation.  Are you supposed to supply `f` as well?

Comment: For `f1` I have two use cases: 1. call `y = f1(5)` 2. call `[grad, grad] = y(0)`, just to get the gradient function. later I want to call `grad(123)`. See the edit

Comment: @vardump - What is `f` though?  You don't supply it with your function.  Is it simply just `f(x) = x^2`?  You're still not making it clear for me.

Comment: of course for `x^2` that doesn't make sense. I want it to work with any function, but one example is: `exp(-(x^2)/2) + x^2` . Of course, I could derivate it by hand, but I'm currently learning Matlab and want to use the power of it.

Comment: @vardump - So you should probably **provide the function** as input into the code, correct?

Comment: @vardump avoid doing `[grad,grad]=y(0)` it's unclear what it means on first look, to ignore an output, just use `~`: `[~,grad]=y(0)`.